# NSOutlineView crash on error EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=13

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have NSOutlineView with custom cell named ListCell. I set label and icon to my custom cell. Then NSOutlineView crash on error exc_bad_access code=13. Do you have any idea, how to repair it? Thx for reply.

```
- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
  return [[[DataSingleton sharedData] pages] count];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
  return NO;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
  return item;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
  ListTableCellView *cell = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"ListCell" owner:self];

  cell.label.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", index + 1];
  [cell.label setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];

  if ([self.icons objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", index]])
    [[cell icon] setImage:[self.icons objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", index]]];

  return cell;
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldSelectItem:(id)item {
 return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Simply I changed NSOutlineView to NSTableView and everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

These methods are the data source delegate methods.  As such they should be concerned only with handling the **data**.  What you are doing here makes no sense to me.

The view will expect back objects that it can use in its table cell's `setStringValue:` etc methods.  Giving back a custom cell in `-outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:` is probably going to confuse it.

Also, I don't think you are handling the counts properly.  `-outlineView:numberOfChildrenOfItem:` should return the count of sub items to the item passed in.  The index passed in `-outlineView:child:ofItem:` can be anywhere between 0 and that count - 1.

Furthermore, I think you need to ensure that the items you return are consistent between invocations of `-reloadData`.  So, if, say, the view asks for child 5 of item nil (nil means the "root level" item) you should consistently return the same object each time.  I haven't seen this documented anywhere, but I had a similar problem once where I was generating the objects on the fly.